# AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent, Dialog closes when account selected

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm trying to use the intent generated by Google Play Services to select the google account

```
private void showGoogleAccountPicker() {
    Intent googlePicker = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null,
        new String[] { GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE }, true, null, null, null, null);
    startActivityForResult(googlePicker, PICK_ACCOUNT_REQUEST);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PICK_ACCOUNT_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      String accountName = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
      Log.d(TAG, "Account Name=" + accountName);
    }
  }
```

The dialog shows my google account and the option to create a new one.

[image]

If I choose the "Add Account" option I'm correctly redirected to the account creation wizard, but if I choose the existing account and click "Ok", the dialog closes but it never returns to the Activity

The Logcat only prints this line. I don't think it has anything to do.

```
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(23576): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

**sources**

http://gmariotti.blogspot.com.es/2013/03/snippet-google-picker-account.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/AccountPicker.html

Comment: What do you mean 'never returns to the Activity'? Does `onActivityResult` get called at all?

Comment: that's exactly what I mean. I've tried debugging and Log.d and it never gets in there.

Comment: thanks for your interest ian, but as usual it was a dumb mistake that took me hours to find.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out my Activity wasn't in the Back Stack because I was explicitly requesting it in the Manifest

```
<activity
            android:name=".ui.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:noHistory="true"
```

so the Dialog couldn't find anyone to return the result to.

What a waste of time :(

Comment: I also had a problem like this and the cause was android:launchMode="singleInstance" in the manifest